# Returning image url's to the front-end from Postgres - Node / React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have a function within my app that I have working that lets me submit a form with images that then stores the image in a file using Multer and uploads a URL to my Postgres database. When I return the file to the front end I am just left with filename that relates to the images but I don't know how to get the file path added so that the image displaying.

**Should I be adding the prefix file path when inserting it into the database? Or is there a security issue if I display the full file path on the front-end. Obviously I know my front and backends should be decoupled and operating independently. I could also have a separate file for images outside of the backend but I am not sure if this is a recommended process. If this was in a professional environment would It just be handled by the likes of Google Cloud, AWS etc so I'm not sure if following the decoupling process is completely possible in this case.**

I have seen process-cwd in some similar cases but I'm not sure if this is what I need to do. Could I hard code the file path in the front-end React component and then use the redux data that has the filename at the end?

I have the photo filename stored in my Redux store however I don't know to go from there. The image is in my backend/assets file at the minute.

[image]

API inserting the image into Postgres.

```
exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {

    const fileNameWithExtension = `${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`

    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send(500)
            }
            console.log(req.body)
            diveSpot.create({
                diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
                diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
                diveSpotTypeID: req.body.diveSpotTypeID,
                diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
                photos: fileNameWithExtension,
            }).then((data) => {
                res.send(data)
            })
```

**Update**

In the below method. I notice that I can enter a file name easily in the "const fileNameWithExtension" line. Can I enter a url for the public file on my front-end or should I make a file in my backend public with express. Should I be putting a file from my backend into my front-end again as it is technically already being submitted from the front-end then multer would move it to the front?

I have included my latest error message below.

```
exports.createArticle = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const fileNameWithExtension = "../home/backend/assets/article/"`${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/article/${fileNameWithExtension}`
    console.log(req.body)
    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send(500)
            }
            article.create({
                articleTitle: req.body.articleTitle,
                articleContent: req.body.articleContent,
                userID: req.body.userID,
                articleTypeID: req.body.articleTypeID,
                photos: fileNameWithExtension,
            }).then((data) => {
                res.send(data)
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the post.',
                    })
                })
        }
    )}
```

error message

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\assets\article\678c78
193bb73ab287bbb6b644a0c86e' -> 'C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\WebApp\sustainable-scuba-web-app\public\article\678c78193bb73ab28
7bbb6b644a0c86e-sharkfeat.jpg'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '...\\SustainableScuba\\backend\\assets\\article\\678c78193bb73ab287bbb6b644a0c86e',
  dest: '...\\sustainable-scuba-web-app\\public\\article\\678c78193bb73ab287bbb6b644a0c86
e-sharkfeat.jpg'
}
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead controllers\article.controller.js:15:21
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "articles" ("articleID","articleTitle","articleContent","photos","userID","articleTypeID") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)
 RETURNING *;
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (...\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:1
0)
```

It is being rendered on the front-end in Redux and is in the store. I am trying to display the image on the card component below.

```
         <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                        <MoreVertIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                }
                title={articleList.articleTitle}
                subheader={userID}/>
            <CardMedia
                id="Photos"
                className={classes.media}
                image={articleList.photos}
                title="Dive Photos"/>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography className="Type" id="Type" variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    {articleType}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the folder in which you save the images as public in express? If on the frontend you get "someimage.jpg" as a response from the server it should be easy to set the src to **your backend address/the public folder with images/the image name**

Comment: I would store the url to the image somewhere in your database and return that to the client. The client needs the full url one way or another to display the image so it's not a security issue. This also allows you to change where your media is stored in the future without having to change your app code. For example you may switch from hosting media files yourself to a Content Delivery Network. In that case your app would break without an update since it only has the filename and not the full url to the image.

Comment: How do i add the prefix to the filename so that the images can be located on the front-end? I assume this should be on the controller API in the backend.

Comment: Are there any security concerns on the uploaded images?  Can they be published like blog content in a public folder, or do they need to be shown only to authorized users like personal photos?

Comment: The error indicates older error handling code, so it is probably hiding the real problem: `express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead`.  It sounds like your upload is working, can you show how you are returning the image to the front end to render?

Comment: I have the filepath in my Redux store. Should this be a URL as in HTTP address?

Comment: Yes.  Once on the server, the content should reference a URL on your backend server (or some other published location).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bad security practice to include full paths of your backend because it allows an attacker to traverse your installation and find exploits.  It is also better to split up a complex application into different simpler responsibilities so that they are easier to solve.

This solution should 'separate the concerns' of the backend and frontend, as well as the two use cases to upload and download the file:

**Use Case 1: Upload an image file to the server.**

- User selects image file from Client system
- Client reads and uploads the file to the server
- Server saves the file and associates it to content. (*this is the sample code*)

**Use Case 2: Download and display an image file for a matching article on the UI.**

- Client requests an article
- Server sends article content and ID for image files
- Client requests image files and assigns the response to image components.
- Server retrieves file by ID and returns it to the client.
- Client image components render image files on the client system.

So, your backend needs to save the file in some way that it can publish it for later use.  The best-practice as mentioned in comments is to put the file in a public folder and use the name as the ID, then let the webserver treat it as a static file.  This allows the full benefit of web and cloud technologies to help you speed up and maintain your solution.

When the client uploads the image, the server should save it to a public folder and return its name/ID.  The client path to the file is not enough in the upload, because the server can't access the client's system.  Instead, the client needs to send a stream of bytes with metadata in the HTTP request.  If you are only setting the filename in the upload, you need to read and send the bytes to the server like so:

JSON Example:

```
  // read in the file bytes when opened:
        onFileOpened(e) {
          let data={};
          let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = () => { 
                  data.image= reader.result ;
                };
           reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
           data.id=generateId(); 
        
       }
        // send the bytes on submit:
        onSubmit(data){
           POST(data);
        
          }
```

Multipart Example:

With multer, the client is expected to send a Multipart/Form-Data request.  This is falling back to older HTML tech and encoding the bytes similarly as above.  However, it is still bytes in a wrapper.

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

Then when the server receives the stream and invokes the `createArticle` method it should read the bytes and save them to a shared path, DB, or Content Delivery Network (CDN).  The server should host or enable an endpoint to GET the same files from the recorded ID.  Then the content can reference the file by appending the file's ID/name to the image endpoint.

Instead of renaming the file from the client path to the destination, the bytes need to be written to disk:

```
   fs.createReadStream(req.file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(newPath ));
```

This allows for the images to be hosted on multiple providers, allows many instances of your webserver to run in parallel, and allows you to size uploads and download services independently.